# Using Dagger and Robolectric with test application

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, robolectric, android-mvp

I am using MVP pattern with a Fragment(`GalleryFragment`), where Application class(`MainApplication`) sources `MainActivityRepository` and `GalleryFragmentPresenter`(grouped as `DIModules`) which are provided to Fragment through field injection.

To test `GalleryFragment` in isolation, my idea was to use Robolectric configuration(@Config) to replace `MainApplication` entirely with a custom `TestApplication` sourcing `mockDIModules`.

`GalleryFragmentTest` runs until `startFragment(galleryFragment)` but I get a NullPointerException at `MainApplication.getComponent().inject(this);` inside `GalleryFragment`.

I suspect this is because this line specifically uses `MainApplication` while everything else is dealt with `TestApplication` set by Robolectric @Config, but I'm not sure and I am looking for advice on how to successfully run tests using this custom `TestApplication`.

While searching for possible solutions, I found out about using AndroidInjector from Dagger support library, which will get rid of `MainApplication.getComponent().inject(this);` entirely but would this work?
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-and-dagger-2-10-androidinjector-5e9c523679a3

GalleryFragment.java

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    @Inject
    public MainActivityRepository mRepository;
    @Inject
    public GalleryFragmentPresenter mGalleryFragmentPresenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainApplication.getComponent().inject(this);   //NullPointerException here
        mGalleryFragmentPresenter.initialize(mRepository, value);
    }
}
```

DIModules.java

```
@Module
public class DIModules {
    @Provides
    public GalleryFragmentPresenter provideGalleryFragmentPresenter(){
        return new GalleryFragmentPresenter();
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public MainActivityRepository provideMainActivityRepository(){
        return new MainActivityRepository();
    }
}
```

AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = DIModules.class)
public interface AppComponent {
        void inject(GalleryFragment galleryFragment);
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        component = buildComponent();
    }
    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
    protected AppComponent buildComponent(){
        return DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .dIModules(new DIModules())
                .build();
    }
}
```

TestApplication.java

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
    public static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = buildComponent();
    }
    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
    protected AppComponent buildComponent(){
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .dIModules(new mockDIModules())
                .build();
    }
}
```

GalleryFragmentTest.java

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
        application = TestApplication.class)
public class GalleryFragmentTest {
    @Test
    public void allItemTabTest() throws Exception {
        GalleryFragment galleryFragment = GalleryFragment.newInstance(value);
        startFragment(galleryFragment);
        assertNotNull(galleryFragment);
    }
}
```

I am using `dagger`, `dagger-android-support`, `dagger-compiler` version 2.14.1 and `robolectric:3.6.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is `null`. Your fragment still tries to work with production application while you're doing things in the test application.

Change your injection code to next:

```
((MainApplication) getContext().getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);
```

And also make the method in your Application `getComponent()` as not static, so test app overrides it.

Another option is to change your `TestApplication` to next:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildComponent();
    }

    private void buildComponent(){
        Application.component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .dIModules(new mockDIModules())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got ClassCastException after making the changes but extending `MainApplication` fixed it. Thanks for the help :)